# DetailsODBC: ERROR[HY000] [Simba][BigQuery] (115) Operation Timeout. PollJob

Tags: powerquery, simba

Ive got a problem when trying to create a new visual for a query (source is Google BigQuery).

I'm using a similar query, that is already working (but with an extra filter), making the new query take a little longer.

It runs for about 10 minutes, and return this error message:

Details: "ODBC: ERROR[HY000] [Simba][BigQuery] (115) Operation timeout.PollJob"

So add an time limit parameter: "connect timeout=10000", but it doesnt work neither.

driver={Simba ODBC Driver for Google BigQuery};oauthmechanism=1;refreshtoken=TOKEN;catalog=mm-datamart-kd;connect timeout=10000

[image]

If someone get the error or have a solution for this error message. I would be grateful if you give me your advised.

Thanks!

Comment: You're using ODBC, not the Google BigQuery connector?

Comment: yes Im using a OBDC driver for Google BigQuery, I have some others query like this one and works, Im just havig this error message on this one.

Comment: So, try the Google BigQuery connector?

Comment: I need an query as an intermediary, when I try to do it with Google BigQuery connector it only let choose by whole tables.

Comment: Yep. So you would build any further logic required in the Power Query steps. Or if you prefer you can save your SELECT as a BQ view, and connect Power BI to that.

Comment: The thing that concern me is that Im using a query almost indentical (this new one have less filters so it give you more data) in another reported and it runs without problem. The new query runs on BigQuery but when I try to run it on PowerB it give me that message...